# How does the `Display` trait auto implement the `ToString` trait in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm at [Ch10-02](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#using-trait-bounds-to-conditionally-implement-methods) in the Rust Programming Lang which covers *blanket implementations*.

[The docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) for the `Display` trait state that:

> Implementing this trait for a type will automatically implement the ToString trait for the type, allowing the usage of the .to_string() method. Prefer implementing the Display trait for a type, rather than ToString.

I understand that there is a statement somewhere in the source that looks something like this:

```
impl<T: Display> ToString for T {
    // --snip--
}
```

And I also understand that implementing `Display` automatically gets you `ToString`, but where is this linkage defined? It's unclear to me how you can tell when a blanket implementation is being applied.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, blanket implementations are defined with the trait that they're implementing, so in the case of `impl<T: Display> ToString for T` the blanket impl should appear alongside `ToString`. We can see this in [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#impl-ToString-for-T), which list just such an impl.

Comment: Thank you! `implementors` are what I was looking for, and the implementation is also here in the source: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2526

Comment: It's not only generally so, the same crate is the only place you can define blanket implementations due to the orphan rules.